# Ember reset items in Ember data when returning to route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a route in my Ember app which returns a set of records in the model hook like so:

```
model() {
  return this.store.findAll('pending-post');
}
```

Assuming this returns 10 records, I can see the 10 records in the data tab of Ember Inspector, and when I log `{{model}}`. The network tab also shows that an array of 10 records returned in the data object.

I then go to another route in my app and edit a post so that it is no longer pending. This change is persisted to the backend.

When I return to the dashboard, the model hook runs again. The request in the network tab now returns an array of 9 objects, as the API is only returning 9 items.

However, the data tab in Ember inpector still shows 10 items and there are still 10 items in `{{model}}`.

What is the best way to force Ember data to remove the item that was not returned by the API the second time around?

Comment: Are you sure `pending-post` is an entity and not only a subset of `post`? Your use case would be much easier handled by `this.store.query('post', { filter: { pending: true } })` or something similar.

Comment: In this case, pending-post is its own entity, so query params wouldn't help, but I see your point for that use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persisting the record to the backend returns a `Promise`. Hence `store.unloadRecord()` can be used in the `then` handler to remove the record from the store.

```
record.save().then(function(){
    this.store.unloadRecord(record);
});
```

Or before querying for the model, remove all records from the store.

```
model()
{
    this.store.unloadAll('pending-post');
    return this.store.findAll('pending-post');
}
```

The model name can be camelCased or dasherised.